# How do I input multiple units of data and utilize a counter in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, printf, counter

Hello everyone I am trying to get it so my program is able to take multiple users worth of data, and then print all of that data once the while loop is finished (I have the counter set at 1 so one new set of information can be entered after the last, but if it hits the limit of two people it will stop and print the information). I have been able to get the information to print out correctly using user input data, but I am unable to get more than one person to enter the data, and I was unable to print out more than one set of data even when I was able to take in more than just one user's data. How would I do these two things? Here is my code that i have so far:

```
public class credLimit {
public static void main(String[]args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int newBalance = 0;
    int credCounter = 1;


    while(credCounter <= 2){
        System.out.print("Enter account number: ");
        int accNum = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter your beginning balance: ");
        int beginningBalance = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter your total charges this month: ");
        int charges = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter your total credit applied this month: ");
        int credit = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter your allowed credit limit: ");
        int maxcredLimit = input.nextInt();
        newBalance = beginningBalance + charges - credit;
        credCounter = credCounter + 1;

        System.out.printf("%nAccount number: %d%n", accNum);
        System.out.printf("Your new balance: %d%n", newBalance);
        if(newBalance <= maxcredLimit)
            System.out.printf("You have not exceeded your credit limit. %d%n");
        else if (newBalance > maxcredLimit)
            System.out.printf("Credit limit exceeded. %d%n");
    }
}
```

I was able to take multiple sets of information in before, but now I can only get one of the users data to be taken, calculated (to determine if their credit limit had been exceeded), and printed out. For some reason it keeps stopping at one user's information instead of letting two user's put in their information, why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your code is crashing since you didn't pass in any arguments to those last 2 print statements:

```
if(newBalance <= maxcredLimit)
    System.out.printf("You have not exceeded your credit limit. %d%n");
else if (newBalance > maxcredLimit)
    System.out.printf("Credit limit exceeded. %d%n");
```

Did you mean:

```
if(newBalance <= maxcredLimit)
    System.out.printf("You have not exceeded your credit limit. %d%n", newBalance);
else if (newBalance > maxcredLimit)
    System.out.printf("Credit limit exceeded. %d%n", newBalance);
```

Comment: How is that, it still allows for one set of data to correctly be processed, why not two?

Comment: Are you working in an IDE? I'm thinking your program crashed and you didn't look at the errors in the console it provides.

Even for a single set of data, did your code print out either of those print statements?
When I ran your code, your program crashed right after taking input for the first set of data and it was because of those print statements.

Comment: I am using an IDE, and do get the first set of data to work, (Eclipse), however I do get this exact error code after the data: Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier 'd'
 at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.PrintStream.format(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.PrintStream.printf(Unknown Source)
 at MyName_Project.credLimit.main(credLimit.java:30)

Comment: That's the behavior I'm describing.  I agree it lets you enter in the first set of data, but it crashes immediately after for the reason I explained.  
The reason you can enter the first set of data is because those print statements are located after input calls in your code.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that silly mistake of mine (can't believe I missed that), thank you for the help!